# Смешивание assembler'а и c

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Здравствуйте! <strike>Пишу свою операционку. Очень понравилась MikeOS, но она вся на ассемблере. Пытаюсь сделать свою. Есть код на Ассемблере:</strike>

```
    BITS 16

extern main

start:

    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288 
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax


    mov si, text_string 
    call clear_screen
    call print_string
    jmp $
    text_string db 'EOS ready', 0

    ;call main

clear_screen:
    pusha

    mov dx, 0

    mov ah, 6
    mov al, 0
    mov bh, 7
    mov cx, 0
    mov dh, 24
    mov dl, 79
    int 10h

    popa
    ret

print_string:   
    mov ah, 0Eh 

.repeat:
    lodsb       
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        
    int 10h     
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret

    times 510-($-$$) db 0   
    dw 0xAA55
```

Это жалкое подобие загрузчика системы.
Также есть код на Си, описывающий функцию `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int main (void)
{
    char* str = "print from C :)";
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Как это все склеить вместе? (Смешать Си и Ассемблер)?

---

Как вызвать функцию, описанную в файле си, в программе на ассемблере? 
При попытке компиляции такого кода:

```
void kernel_main(){
    ...
}

...
call kernel_main
...
```

пишет:

```
boot/boot.s:16: error: symbol `kernel_main' undefined
```

Что как указать компилятору nasm, где эта функция?

Comment: Вряд ли взлетит в таком виде. Если вы запускаете код наподобие загрузчика системы, вам не будет доступна рантайм-библиотека, поэтому о `printf` можно забыть.

Comment: Как тогда? Писать все библиотеки самому?

Comment: Какой ваш юзкейс? Расскажите, какую задачу вы на самом деле решаете.

Comment: Пишу свою операционку. Очень понравилась MikeOS, но она вся на ассемблере. Пытаюсь сделать свою.

Comment: Окей, понял. Смотрите. Если операционка под вашим контролем, то и доступ к файлам, и загрузчик разделяемых библиотек тоже в ваших руках. Это значит, вы сможете по идее загрузить динамические библиотеки в нужный момент. Вопрос только в том, доступно ли это всё сразу после отработки вашей ассемблерной части, или система должна сначала проинициализироваться.

Comment: В любом случае, вы должны чётко представлять себе, как в вашей операционке будет реализована поддержка динамических библиотек. Возможно, вам придётся допилить компилятор/линковщик, чтобы он генерировал код, совместимый с вашей моделью.

Comment: Инициализация пока не нужна. Поэтому, можно сразу после загрузки их подгрузить.

Comment: В любом случае, если загрузчик ваш, то вам не составит труда загрузить и скомпилированный код на C. Если вы хотите скомпоноваться статически, просто скомпилируйте два объектных модуля и слинкуйте их между собой.

Comment: Думаю, на первом этапе о динамических библиотеках нужно забыть. А также на первых порах придется соредоточиться на конкретном железе. Можно, конечно, начать с написания начального загрузчика с железа, а можно (для x86) пойти другим путем (наверное уже сотни раз пройденным) -- грузить и запускать ядро из DOS (вытесняя его после загрузки). Само собой, вначале делаете монолитное статически собранное ядро (все необходимые библиотечные функции вплоть до обращения к BIOS статически прилинкованы).  Писать ли все самому? Вряд ли это нужно -- берите  сорсы из GNU.

Comment: Думаю с материалами, выводимыми гуглом по запрсу "пишем начальный загрузчик" (например, https://dev64.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/os_boot_loader_dev_02/ , http://www.cyberforum.ru/assembler-os/thread975264.html , http://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.myosdev/201207/01022505.html и т.д.) и аналогичными Вы уже ознакомились?  /  Что же касается непосредственно вопроса о смешении ассемблера и си, то можно посмотреть http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html или поискать аналоги для других сред программирования.

Comment: Да, познакомился, но все равно - огромное спасибо за ваше участие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern void kernel_main();

void kernel_main() {...}
```

asm: .globl _kernel_main
....

```
call _kernel_main
```

Это если дальше не "копать", но в инете есть развернутые обсуждения этих вопросов, прежде всего ассемблеры бывают разные и разные ключевые слова используются ими, и что самое неприятное - они ориентированны на конкретное семейство процессоров (intel и arm не совместимы на уровне исполняемых кодов) ...
[(en) gcc & asm:x86](http://www.locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/)[wasm.ru что-то сильно под реконструкцией](http://www.wasm.ru/wault/)[кое что древнее](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/from_c_to_asm.txt.html)

- но- все равно вопрос остается начинать с таких сложностей?! Надеюсь, что пыл не остынет, и кроме ос-майка есть операционки, в которых было-бы нескучно разбираться...
- п.с. сишный рантайм тоже можно использовать в ассемблере, если его подключить, у "с" он не такой жирный, а часто и размещается в динамической библиотеке, но ядра имеют свой рантайм.

Comment: Окей, спасибо! Вместо ```-f bin``` добавил ```-f aout```