# Написание лексера: алгоритм

Tags: c, компилятор, лексер

Здравствуйте! Пишу лексер. Делаю так: считываю один символ из файла, смотрю, что за символ:

```
switch(_symbol){
        case '.': return "[symbol: DOT]";
...
}
```

Но чтобы определить, ключевое ли это слово, приходится считать еще символы. Вижу, что это плохой способ. Как сделать это лучше?

Comment: а почему не канонический `lex`?

Comment: А без него не как? Хочется самому.

Comment: Конечно, можно и самому. Просто @VladD предполагает, что вы не в курсе, что существуют готовые инструменты, которые по заданной грамматике строят лексер, и вы зря изобретаете велосипед. При условии наличия `lex`'а самостоятельное написание лексера приемлемо разве что в образовательных целях.

Comment: Да с контекстно-зависимыми грамматиками иногода может быть проблема. Вот обычное решение: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack . Просто перекачивать туда таблицу идентификаторов. Хотя можно просто проигнорировать и выдать два токена через или, а синтаксический анализатор потом пусть сам разбирается с этим(так делает clang).

Comment: @igumnov: Если речь идёт лишь о детектировании ключевых слов, таких проблем возникнуть не должно по идее.

Comment: @igumnov: Но да, знать про lexer hack стоит.

Comment: @VladD у меня есть [подозрение что ТС пытается создать свой компилятор и потом написать на нем еще одну ОС](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416456) так что это наверняка будет ему полезно.

Comment: @igumnov: Значит, скоро стоит ждать вопросов о синтаксическом анализаторе :) (_ушёл перечитывать Dragon Book_)

Comment: @VladD Да это хорошая книжка. ТС советую тебе подробно ознакомится с её содержанием.  *Ахо, Ульман, "Компиляторы. Принципы, технологии, инструментарий"* на русском вроде называется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. Во-первых, вы не можете выяснить, найдено ли ключевое слово до тех пор, пока вы не просмотрите входящий текст до конца этого самого ключевого слова. Отсюда выплывает простой алгоритм: прочитать символы до конца слова, и поискать это слово в таблице ключевых слов.

Для поиска в таблице можно использовать простой перебор, и этого обычно достаточно, если ключевых слов разумное количество.

Но можно и сделать сложнее/эффективнее: применить алгоритм наподобие [Ахо—Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA), который эффективно умеет искать набор строк в тексте. (Для этого внутри строиться `trie`, префиксное дерево, о котором шло [обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417593/10105) недавно.)

Заметьте, что существует популярная утилита `lex` (и её open source-аналог `flex`), которая делает именно это: по набору ключевых слов (а также регулярных выражений, так что `lex` более продвинутая штука) строит нужное поисковое дерево, и выдаёт вам исходный код на C, который нужно просто подключить к проекту.

Comment: Черт, такой годный алгоритм и такие смешные фамилии у авторов (если немного подправить): *Ухо - Карасик*.

Comment: @igumnov: Я примерно так и запоминал название ;-)

Comment: @igumnov Самое смешное, что Корасик - это женщина. Кстати, Ахо - это тот, из-за кого 'awk' начинается на 'a'.

Comment: @Shamow Да уж, гигантские размеры UNIXа причудливо смешивают людей друг с другом.

Comment: @Shamov; И который один из соавторов Dragon Book, кстати.

Answer (score 1):

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать самопальный парсер, то хорошим началом будет такой метод. Нужно создать в памяти массив объектов, каждый из которых будет отвечать за распознавание определённого слова. После считывания очередного символа из входного потока этот символ по очереди "показывается" каждому из этих объектов. На что каждый из них может "отреагировать" тремя способами:

1. Символ вообще не в струю. Если объект уже продвинулся в распознавании своего слова, то он сбрасывает состояние и пробует начать распознавание с начала.
2. Символ более-менее в тему, хотя ещё не известно, будет ли в итоге полное слово. Объект меняет своё состояние, продвигаясь на один шаг вперёд по тому слову, которое он умеет распознавать.
3. Символ успешно завершает то слово, которое начало распознаваться ранее. Объект как-то сообщает об успехе.

Всякий раз, когда происходит 3), состояние всех объектов нужно принудительно сбросить в начальное.

В принципе, ситуации 1) и 2) отличаются лишь тем, как меняется внутренее состояние распознающего объекта. С точки зрения внешнего цикла обе ситуации должны выглядеть одинаково: пока ничего не обнаружено, нужны ещё символы. Но для большей эффективности можно эти ситуации различать, передвигая в начало очереди те объекты, которые уже частично что-то распознали. Вероятность ситуации 3) для них выше, поэтому следующие символы лучше "показывать" в первую очередь им.

Comment: Это по сути упрощённый вариант Ахо—Корасик без отката к промежуточному состоянию. Он не распознает паттерн типа XXY в тексте XXXY (т. к. откатится в нулевое состояние на третьем Х), но должен сработать, если ключевые слова не содержат пробелов (и оканчиваются пробелами).

Comment: @VladD Да, он без возвратов. Но зато существенно проще. Честно говоря, я думаю, что "карасик" (я его так ласково называю) предназначен для совсем других вещей. Не для парсеров, а для проверки орфографии, например. В общем, для таких случаев, когда поисковых строк многие тысячи.

Comment: Ну, lex использует именно его, насколько я понимаю. Точнее, ещё более сложную FSM, т. к. там возможны регулярки.

Comment: @VladD Конечно, более сложную. Скорее всего с "карасиком" она имеет общего только то, что это тоже конечный автомат, немного похожий по структуре.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что в случае, когда регулярки тривиальны, получается именно _карасик_. Чувствую, но доказать не могу (c)

Comment: @VladD Я в этом даже не сомневаюсь. Скорее всего при определённых условиях lex генерируeт шаблонную реализацию карасика. При других условиях - реализацию чего-то ещё. А по сложному пути идёт в самом крайнем случае.